# Animating an SVG helicopter blade

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to animate a helicopter blade. The only idea I have is to shrink and expand the blades along the X-axis. For this, I'm animating the ***scale*** attribute, however the results are not as expected. I'm guessing the issue is regarding *transform-origin*? Not sure how to fix this, would be great if somebody could help.

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <g id="helicopter" transform="translate(0,0)">
     <g transform="rotate(10 425.701 270.25)">
       <path d="M452.992 256.303v4.547h-1.416l-2.435 9.914h8.814l-2.133-9.914h-1.312v-4.547zm1.252 27.766l-.695.475v2.377l-5.307.006a.858.858 0 000 1.716h23.242l.387-.1 3.096-1.7v-.006a.8.8 0 10-.795-1.385v-.004l-2.285 1.365-.412.113-4.934-.006v-2.318h-1.566v2.318h-9.854v-2.318z M425.701 270.25h42.348c8.82.017 10.296 13.596 0 14.352h-13.44c-4.794-.054-9.567-3.488-9.7-9.7l-20.315-2.173-1.944 3.617c-.443.672-1.027 1.005-1.8.881l.505-5.053v-2.43l-1.819-8.894c.921-.056 1.446.338 1.794.93z" style="fill:#121212"/>
       <path id="blades" d="M481.292 257.313 H426.21 v3.032 l21.124 -.809 v-1.213 h12.835 v1.213 l21.124 .81z" style="fill:#aaaaaa;stroke-width:1px"/>
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#blades" type="scale" values="1 1;0 1;1 1" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" dur="1s" begin="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#helicopter" type="translate" from="-600" to="200" dur="25s" begin="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Helicopter blades can be rotated with `rotateY (360deg)`

Set the center of rotation using CSS rules

```
#blades {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
}
```

Full code:

```css
#blades {
transform-origin:center;
transform-box:fill-box;
animation: blades 0.15s  infinite;
}
@keyframes blades {
100% {transform:rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 200 500 500">
  <g id="helicopter" transform="translate(0,0)">
     <g transform="rotate(10 425.701 270.25)">
       <path d="M452.992 256.303v4.547h-1.416l-2.435 9.914h8.814l-2.133-9.914h-1.312v-4.547zm1.252 27.766l-.695.475v2.377l-5.307.006a.858.858 0 000 1.716h23.242l.387-.1 3.096-1.7v-.006a.8.8 0 10-.795-1.385v-.004l-2.285 1.365-.412.113-4.934-.006v-2.318h-1.566v2.318h-9.854v-2.318z M425.701 270.25h42.348c8.82.017 10.296 13.596 0 14.352h-13.44c-4.794-.054-9.567-3.488-9.7-9.7l-20.315-2.173-1.944 3.617c-.443.672-1.027 1.005-1.8.881l.505-5.053v-2.43l-1.819-8.894c.921-.056 1.446.338 1.794.93z" style="fill:#121212"/>
       <path id="blades" d="M481.292 257.313 H426.21 v3.032 l21.124 -.809 v-1.213 h12.835 v1.213 l21.124 .81z" style="fill:#aaaaaa;stroke-width:1px"/>
        </g>
    </g>
  <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" xlink:href="#helicopter" type="translate" from="-400" to="100" dur="25s" begin="0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
</svg>
```